# How can I concatenate the values from multiple rows in Excel in a single row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table which displays 2 entities. Because `Entity A` contains multiple `Entity B`, I have one row for each combination of A and B, in a **cartesian product**.

What I need is to transform this table in such a way that the columns from `Entity A` will be distinct, and I need to concatenate the values of `Entity B`.

### Example

Here we got 2 tables, the first one is **my original**. On the second one, the first few rows are grouped/concatenated exactly like I need it.

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this grouping/concatenation?

Comment: Excel 2016 CONCAT would be the solution for you, unfortunately previous verdict doesn't have it.  You can still achieve it concatenating the values in a helper column.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thanks! Do you mean creating another column for the concatenated values?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have Office 2016, so, if you know a solution, please. Thank you.